# how to add admobs on android

Tags: android, admob

Please assist with something,I am trying to add admobs on the app but it doesn't show on the app when I run it, but it appears on the android studio preview. How do I fix that?

This code is on the main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relatively"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d15400"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.90"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/score"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Score : 1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timers"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="00:00:49"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.40" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="15*2*1-1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="35.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="30"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="29"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="32"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp" />





            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
```

this code is on the questions activity class -

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

this is the cose on the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hitesh.asimplegame">

    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".QuestionActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><![CDATA[
       android:name=".ResultActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        ]]>
        <activity android:name=".Finish" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScrean" />
        <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is for resources

```
resources>
    <string name="app_name">A simple game</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_admobs">admobs</string>
    <!-- -
        This is an ad unit ID for a banner test ad. Replace with your own banner ad unit id.
        For more information, see https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638
    <!- -->
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">4526809957646802/687614978</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>6

    <string name="interstitial_ad_sample">Interstitial Ad Sample</string>
    <string name="start_level">Level 1</string>
    <string name="next_level">Next Level</string>
    <!-- -
        This is an ad unit ID for an interstitial test ad. Replace with your own interstitial ad unit id.
        For more information, see https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638
    <!- -->
    <string name="interstitial_ad_unit_id">4526809957646802/6876146978</string>
    <string name="title_activity_doa">doa</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: which emulator you used... testing time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ad ids should start with ca-app-pub-your_key
both the ids, banner id as well as interstitial ids

so use these :

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-4526809957646802/687614978</string>
<string name="interstitial_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-4526809957646802/6876146978</string>
```

Comment: If it worked then please dont forget to mark this answer as accepted  , so that others can also get help from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issues with the code. The problem is that, You may created that ad unit id some minutes ago. So it took some more time to appear in the real device. If you really want to know the code is working or not, please set the banner id to `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`. It is a preview id and it will work for you.

Comment: Also don't forget to add "ca-app-pub-"

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hope this will help you:
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/relatively"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#d15400"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Linear_ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     />
   <LinearLayout/>



 AdView adview;
LinearLayout linearads;
private AdBannerListener adBannerListener;
oncreate:
 setAdvertise();

 private void setAdvertise()
{
    try{

        try{



            layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Linear_ad);


            adview= new AdView(CAboutActivity.this);
            adview.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
            adview.setAdUnitId("adUnit id");
            adview.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            layout.addView(adview);
            adview.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            //linear_ad
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        adview.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Log.d("On Fail called", "Ad");
                    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("On Load called","Ad");
                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```